# Concatenate cell text with up to 100 leading characters of another cell's text

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data. Column B has 8 characters of data and begins at row 11. Column C has extensive data and begins at row 11 as well.

I am trying to take the first 8 characters in a cell in column B, combine it with up to 100 characters in column C, and place this combined data into column A. This will loop for the next 200 rows of data.

```
Sub concat()
For X = 11 To 200
    Range("A" & X).Value = Left("B" & X, 8) & Right("C" & X, 100)
Next X
End Sub
```

Original data:

```
A            B                  C
             testdata          SomeExtremelylongtext...
```

Expected Results:

```
A                                                  B                  C
testdataSomeExtremelylongtext...                testdata          SomeExtremelylongtext...
```

What I get:

```
A                         B                  C
B11C11                testdata          SomeExtremelylongtext...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
Range("A" & X).Value = Left("B" & X, 8) & Right("C" & X, 100)
```

to:

```
Range("A" & X).Value = Left(Range("B" & X), 8) & Right(Range("C" & X), 100)
```

You are literally finding the left 8 of the text string "B11" and the Right 100 of the text string "C11", when you want the values in the ranges B11 and C11.

Comment: Thank you!. I am extremely new to excel macros (today), so it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want the first 100 characters from "C" then change `RIGHT` to `LEFT`

```
Range("A" & X).Value = Left(Range("B" & X).Value, 8) & Left(Range("C" & X).Value, 100)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!. I thought RIGHT put it at the end of the destination box, but upon reading your answer I was way off!. thank you very much.